# isar_generator build failing due to switch statements

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

When running `dart run build_runner build --verbose` I get the following errors:

```
[SEVERE] isar_generator on lib/ui/responsive/responsive_layout.dart:

This builder requires Dart inputs without syntax errors.
However, package:plant_monitor/ui/responsive/responsive_layout.dart (or an existing part) contains the following errors.
responsive_layout.dart:13:16: Expected a type name.
responsive_layout.dart:13:16: Expected to find '['.
responsive_layout.dart:13:16: Expected to find ':'.
And 9 more...

Try fixing the errors and re-running the build.

package:build_resolvers/src/resolver.dart 218:9  AnalyzerResolver.compilationUnitFor.<fn>
package:pool/pool.dart 127:28                    Pool.withResource
package:source_gen/src/builder.dart 373:18       _hasAnyTopLevelAnnotations
package:source_gen/src/builder.dart 89:11        _Builder.build

[SEVERE] isar_generator on lib/ui/widgets/card_tags.dart:

This builder requires Dart inputs without syntax errors.
However, package:plant_monitor/ui/widgets/card_tags.dart (or an existing part) contains the following errors.
card_tags.dart:11:12: Expected an identifier.
card_tags.dart:16:12: Expected an identifier.
card_tags.dart:16:21: Expected a type name.
And 9 more...

Try fixing the errors and re-running the build.

package:build_resolvers/src/resolver.dart 218:9  AnalyzerResolver.compilationUnitFor.<fn>
package:pool/pool.dart 127:28                    Pool.withResource
package:source_gen/src/builder.dart 373:18       _hasAnyTopLevelAnnotations
package:source_gen/src/builder.dart 89:11        _Builder.build

[FINE] isar_generator on lib/entities/user.dart:Running IsarCollectionGenerator - 1 of 2
[FINE] isar_generator on lib/entities/user.dart:Running IsarEmbeddedGenerator - 2 of 2
[FINE] isar_generator on lib/entities/plant.dart:Running IsarCollectionGenerator - 1 of 2
[FINE] isar_generator on lib/entities/plant.dart:Running IsarEmbeddedGenerator - 2 of 2
[FINE] isar_generator on lib/entities/image.dart:Running IsarCollectionGenerator - 1 of 2
[FINE] isar_generator on lib/entities/image.dart:Running IsarEmbeddedGenerator - 2 of 2
[INFO] Build:Running build completed, took 8.8s

[INFO] Build:Caching finalized dependency graph...
[INFO] Build:Caching finalized dependency graph completed, took 102ms

[SEVERE] Build:
Failed after 8.9s
```

The code each of these refers to are below:

For:

```
responsive_layout.dart:13:16: Expected a type name.
responsive_layout.dart:13:16: Expected to find '['.
responsive_layout.dart:13:16: Expected to find ':'.
```

The code is (where column numbers are labeled with (HERE)):

```
09    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
10        return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
11          double width = constraints.maxWidth;
12          switch (width) {
13            case < (HERE)400:
14              return Body(screenType: ScreenType.mobile.index);
15            case < 600:
16              return Body(screenType: ScreenType.tablet.index);
17            default:
18              return Body(screenType: ScreenType.desktop.index);
19          }
20        });
21      }
```

For:

```
card_tags.dart:11:12: Expected an identifier.
card_tags.dart:16:12: Expected an identifier.
card_tags.dart:16:21: Expected a type name.
```

The code is (where column numbers are labeled with (HERE)):

```
10      switch (days) {
11            case (HERE)== 0:
12              return Text(
13                "Today",
14                style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
15              );
16            case (HERE)> 1 && < (HERE)100:
17               . . .
18      }
```

Details
Dart SDK Version: `3.1.0`
Flutter Version: `3.13.1`
build_runner: `2.4.6`
Platform: Windows 11

I tried searching the issue on google and looking through the issues under flutter's GitHub and Isar's Github, but there were no mentions of similar issues. I expect it to build because unless I'm a complete idiot my syntax is correct.

Comment: Looks like isar_generator isn't using Dart 3 syntax properly? Maybe see https://github.com/isar/isar/issues/1288 ?